# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification only fires once

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to handle device orientation changes on a viewcontroller for one of my views.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    // Tell the UIDevice to send notifications when the orientation changes
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

// tell the director that the orientation has changed
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"orientationChanged");
}
```

When I first launch the App, the orientationChanged selector gets called, but then after that it does not get called again no matter how much I rotate the iPad.  Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?  When I put similar code in the app delegate, it works fine, but in this particular view controller, it is not behaiving properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but just thought I'd add a link to a tutorial I found when I was in the same situation you were (wanting to get notifications for device rotation, regardless of what the interface orientation was).

[This tutorial](http://the.ichibod.com/kiji/how-to-handle-device-rotation-for-uiviews-in-ios) gives a nice and simple overview of how to handle device rotation using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

I also had issues with `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` not firing (it worked fine in the simulator, but not on my device). After a bit of debugging I realised that I had Portrait Orientation Locked on the device, and this was causing the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` not to fire. Not sure if that's your issue, but it's something that's easy to overlook and worth checking.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that the orientation will not change unless you specify that it can do so. when you rotate the device/simulator, the framework calls

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;`

where interface orientation is the orientation the system wants to use, however you have to return YES or it will not change.

if you are not returning **YES** then your orientation is not changing and therefore you cannot get notified for an orientation change (because it did not happen)

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is for autorotating the view.  I do not want the view to be autorotated.  I just want to receive notifications for when the device has rotated.